# Start SSH connection in PuTTY, run a command, and leave the session active

Tags: ssh, putty

I want to run a few shell commands every time I SSH to a server via PuTTY. I'm connecting to a production web server managed by someone else, and I don't want to store my own scripts there.

I see the option **Connection > SSH > Remote Command**, but if I put my initialization commands there, after starting the session, it closes immediately after the commands execute. How can I run the Remote Command, and then keep the session open so I can continue using it?

Answer (score 6):

The SSH session closes (and PuTTY with it) as soon as the command finishes. By default the "command" is a shell. As you have overridden this default "command" and yet you want to run the shell nevertheless, you have to explicitly execute the shell yourself:

```
my-command ; /bin/bash
```

See also [Executing a specific command on the server](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-command).

Answer (score 2):

One option to go is set up your putty remote command like this:

```
ls > dir.ls & /bin/bash
```

In this example command you want to run is "**ls > dir.ls**" what creates file dir.ls with content of directory listing.

And as you want to leave shell open you can add aditional command "**/bin/bash**" or any other shell of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! Finishing the command by opening a shell was the clue I needed. I added `;bash` at the end of my "Remote command" string (your `& /bin/bash` works too) to start bash and keep the connection open. When I `exit` from bash the Putty window closes as I would expect too, which is nice.

Comment: With the `&`, you run the command **in parallel** with the shell. What is typically not what you want in this case. You typically want to use the `;` instead to run the command **before** the shell. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28826996/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Your comment is true, but running in parallel may be wanted when running command that takes more time and is not allways needed to wait until it ends.